# $this->request->param() and $this->request->post() in kohana 3.2

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-3

what is the difference between `$this->request->param()` and `$this->request->post()` in kohana 3.2?

Somebody explain me briefly.

Thanks

Comment: params includes both get and post where post only includes post variables

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have URL like this: http://example.com/store/books/computer/martin_fowler
with routing defined as follows:

```
Route::set('books', '<controller>/<action>(/<product>(/<category>(/<author>)))')
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'store',
            'action' => '',
        ));
```

`$this->request->param()` this will return:

```
array (
  'product' => 'books', 
  'category' => 'computer',
  'author' => 'martin_fowler',
)
```

`$this->request->post()` will return `$_POST` data.

Both methods will return NULL if the key is not found:

```
$this->request->param('xxx') // NULL
$this->request->param('author') // martin_fowler
$this->request->post('id') // Some id value in $_POST or NULL if id doesn't exist in $_POST
```

Comment: Thanks for your information matino. I understood how $this->request->param() and $this->request->post() is working.

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana

```
$data = $this->request->post();
// get $_POST data
```

returns post data like submit form.

```
$this->request->param()
```

returns posted as well as get data which is send from $_POST and $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

The Param gets request parameters assigned to the request after the routing process whereas post get the raw data POSTed.